# If-then-else in ant properties file

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java Ant project with a build.xml file which internally gets a lot of properties from build.properties. Something like this in build.properties

```
p1=<val1>
p2=<val2>
p3=<val3>
..
```

Now, I want to conditionally modify the properties p2 and p3 based on the the value of p1. Something like:

```
<if p1 == "some_val">
  p2=<new_val>
  p3=<new_val>
<else>
  p2=<new2_val>
  p3=<new2_val>
</if>
```

The problem is, I cannot shift the values p1, p2 and p3 to build.xml because there are many subsequent properties in the file which depend on p1, p2 and p3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<project name="demo" default="go">

  <condition property="p1_someval">
    <equals arg1="${p1}" arg2="someval"/>
  </condition>

  <target name="-go-someval" if="p1_someval">
    <property name="p2" value="newval"/>
    <property name="p3" value="newval"/>
  </target>

  <target name="-go-notsomeval" unless="p1_someval">
    <property name="p2" value="new2val"/>
    <property name="p3" value="new2val"/>
  </target>

  <target name="go" depends="-go-someval,-go-notsomeval">
    <echo message="p2=${p2}"/>
    <echo message="p3=${p3}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, p1, p2 and p3 have already been read from a properties file, which means p2 and p3 can't be written to.  In which case, the solution is to read them from the file using a prefix instead, such as `<property file="build.properties" prefix="file"/>` followed by `<property name="p1" value="${file.p1}"/>`, then continue as above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script with required logic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project">

    <!-- Load only p1 value from build.properties file -->
    <loadproperties srcfile="build.properties">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="^\s*p1\s*=.*$"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>

    <!-- Set p2 and p3 depend on p1 value -->
    <condition property="p2" value="new_val" else="new2_val">
        <equals arg1="${p1}" arg2="some_val" trim="yes"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="p3" value="new_val" else="new2_val">
        <equals arg1="${p1}" arg2="some_val" trim="yes"/>
    </condition>

    <!-- Load other properties -->
    <property file="build.properties"/>

</project>
```